# How to centralize the character encoding used by my JSF pages?

Tags: spring, jsf, character-encoding

I want to **centralize** as possible the character encoding used by my **JSF** pages.

Under **WEB-INF** folder I have two project configuration files, one for development environment (called **projectDEV.properties**), and other for production environment (called **projectPRO.properties**).

The proper bundle is correctly loaded by **Spring** via:

```
<context:property-placeholder 
        location="WEB-INF/project${my.environment}.properties" />
```

...Where '**my.environment**' is a **Tomcat launch configuration parameter**:

```
-Dmy.environment=PRO   or  -Dmy.environment=DEV
```

In this two properties files I have next **property** declaration:

```
cfg.i18n.encoding1=UTF-8
```

And here comes the *question*:

**How can I use that property inside my .xhtml pages?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="${cfg.i18n.encoding}" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">

        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=${cfg.i18n.encoding}" />
            <title>Home</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            HELLO!
        </h:body>

    </f:view>
</html>
```

Thanks!

---

```
/**
 * Servlet 2.3/2.4 Filter that allows one to specify a character encoding for
 * requests. This is useful because current browsers typically do not set a
 * character encoding even if specified in the HTML page or form.
 *
 * <p>This filter can either apply its encoding if the request does not
 * already specify an encoding, or enforce this filter's encoding in any case
 * ("forceEncoding"="true"). In the latter case, the encoding will also be
 * applied as default response encoding on Servlet 2.4+ containers (although
 * this will usually be overridden by a full content type set in the view).
 *
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @since 15.03.2004
 * @see #setEncoding
 * @see #setForceEncoding
 * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding
 * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse#setCharacterEncoding
 */
public class CharacterEncodingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private String encoding;

    private boolean forceEncoding = false;


    /**
     * Set the encoding to use for requests. This encoding will be passed into a
     * {@link javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding} call.
     * <p>Whether this encoding will override existing request encodings
     * (and whether it will be applied as default response encoding as well)
     * depends on the {@link #setForceEncoding "forceEncoding"} flag.
     */
    public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    /**
     * Set whether the configured {@link #setEncoding encoding} of this filter
     * is supposed to override existing request and response encodings.
     * <p>Default is "false", i.e. do not modify the encoding if
     * {@link javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#getCharacterEncoding()}
     * returns a non-null value. Switch this to "true" to enforce the specified
     * encoding in any case, applying it as default response encoding as well.
     * <p>Note that the response encoding will only be set on Servlet 2.4+
     * containers, since Servlet 2.3 did not provide a facility for setting
     * a default response encoding.
     */
    public void setForceEncoding(boolean forceEncoding) {
        this.forceEncoding = forceEncoding;
    }


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (this.encoding != null && (this.forceEncoding || request.getCharacterEncoding() == null)) {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(this.encoding);
            if (this.forceEncoding) {
                response.setCharacterEncoding(this.encoding);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that. I would stick to UTF-8 for now and ever. It's very unlikely if a better character encoding would be invented in the near future. JSF/Facelets also already uses it by default. The *only* thing which you might need to change is the server configuration as to processing request URI/parameters, but this isn't possible this way.

Comment: Thanks BalusC; Yes, we are following the “mantra” of moving to UTF-8 in every place. The want for encoding centralization is more like a cleaning issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to directly reference the configuration property in your JSF page as the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` doesn't expose any API for that.

You could try this trick. Create a regular Java bean like this:

```
public class Config {

  private String charset;

  /* getters + setters */

}
```

Then add it to your Spring configuration like this:

```
<bean id="config" class="com.example.myapp.Config">
  <property name="charset"><value>${cfg.i18n.encoding1}</value></property>
</bean>
```

Then you should be able to read the property like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=#{config.charset}" />
```

Comment: Thanks chkal for the response. It works for substitution in meta declaration, but not in xml encoding substitution (first line of page) because Eclipse doesnt allow me to save the file if I put encoding="#{config.charset}". Anyway, I give you the green stick

Comment: I think there is now way to dynamically set the XML file encoding. At least without hacking the XML parser. And IMHO it doesn't make any sense to do something like this at all. This encoding specifies the encoding of the XML file. And it must be same encoding that the file uses. So why changing that? There is only ONE correct encoding of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can centralize the encoding of your html files using filter provided by SpringFramework for the same. You can define this filter in the web.xml file as following.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: Your answer is a valid answer too. Thanks

Comment: This only sets POST request body encoding to UTF-8 (which JSF by default **already** uses), not GET request URL encoding (which needs to be configured in server), nor HTTP response encoding (which needs to be configured in view, but JSF by default already uses it). This filter is useless for JSF 2.x.

Comment: I put here the source (with its Javadocs) of the CharacterEncodingFilter. I am a little bit confused.

Comment: You don't need to create it yourself. Spring already provides it. Just configure as per Japs' answer. But after all, you don't need it at all as explained in my previous comment.